# Latest version of ReSharper breaks both Bower and project.json 'version intellisense' in ASP.NET Core 1.0 projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, resharper, asp.net-core-1.0

This issue has been going on for a while. I noticed that when my ReSharper is enabled it messes up the version intellisense when in bower.json and project.json.

I like being able to see the latest version at this point:

```
jquery": ...
```

As soon as I disable ReSharper and restart vs2015 all intellisense works again.

Comment: Check its release notes https://www.google.com/search?q=resharper+release+notes&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b and compare to http://corefx.strikingly.com so that you know who comes first. I believe it is ASP.NET Core that breaks ReSharper.

Answer (score 0):

I have notice also with new update Resharper Ultimate 2016.2. As soon as i select VS2015 intellisense it work fine in project.json files but when select resharper it break. Then i select custom option and select json as visualstudio intellisense  and all other select resharper intellisense. After that it work smoothly.